# adding HTML to div if next element has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

firstly here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/rwz7egdz/1/

What I am trying to do is very simple, there are two div's on with class "**panel-heading**" and other with class "**panel-collapse**", there are two conditions,

Condition 1: if 'panel-collapse' has class 'collapse' add some html to 'panel-heading'

Condition 2: if 'panel-collapse' has class 'collapse' add some different html to 'panel-heading'

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
Panel Heading
</div><!-- /.panel-heading-->
<div class="panel-collapse collapse">
    Panel Collapse with a just a collapse
</div><!-- /.panel-collapse -->
<br><br>
<div class="panel-heading">
Panel Heading
</div><!-- /.panel-heading-->
<div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    Panel Collapse with collapse &amp; in 
</div><!-- /.panel-collapse -->
```

**JS Code:**

```
 $( ".panel-heading" ).next().hasClass(".collapse").append( "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>" );

 $( ".panel-heading" ).next().hasClass(".collapse.in").append( "<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>" );
```

I am quite sure I am missing something in the js part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the wording of your two conditions. They look conflicting to me.

Comment: Hi GregL, they seem okay. if panel-collapse has 'collapse' class, panel-heading should be added with some html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to chain `next` and `hasClass`. You can just query `next()`.

```
$(".panel-heading").next(".collapse:not(.in)")
                   .append("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");

$(".panel-heading").next(".collapse.in")
                   .append("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
```

The above works in your fiddle.

For the reason why your initial solution failed, see @cgatian's answer.

EDIT: updated to reflect comment:

```
$(".panel-heading + .collapse:not(.in)").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");
$(".panel-heading + .collapse.in").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
```

So why does this work? we are using the sibling operator to immediately find all .collapse/.collapse.in elements then traversing back up one element and appending to that.

Comment: Hi Darko Z, they get added inside 'panel-collapse', any chance that they get added to 'panel-heading' instead?

Comment: @user3486430 that's a slightly different issue and would mean you are doing something along the lines of: `$(".panel-heading").next().is(selector).previous(".panel-heading").append(...)` but this is a pretty rubbish solution even though it would work. Optimally you would iterate through the `.panel-heading` array $(selector).each() and for each of them check that the next is appropriate and append the right html.

Comment: the reason that iterating through your headings is better is because you are doing less selection and can keep references to your elements instead of constantly reselecting.

Answer (score 3):

The actual reason this failed is because you used:

```
.hasClass(".collapse")
```

There was an extra period within the method call. It should be:

```
.hasClass("collapse")
```

Has class does not need a selector, just the string of the class name

---

**Update:**

After the selector is fixed, hasClass() returns a boolean, not the elements that have the class.  Building on @Darko Z's answer you need the following.

```
$( ".panel-heading" ).next(".collapse").append( "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>" );

 $( ".panel-heading" ).next(".collapse.in").append( "<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brrbq03L/

Comment: +1 for the actual reason, forgot to include that in my answer :)

Comment: @cgatian, thank you for the correction, but even after I change it, it does not work.

Comment: @user3486430 hasClass returns a boolean so it will never work in your case. http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ you are trying to use a jquery method on a true/false value

Comment: Yeah @DarkoZ has the correct answer. I still feel like there should be an even better way to do this.